# remove subfolder name in url using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

i have an site and using the htaccess code for redirections, in that, i have url like `"http://username.domainname.com/userid"` and want to remove the part "userid", so that, the url will look like `"http://username.domainname.com/"`.

i use the following code to get `"http://username.domainname.com/userid"` :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ /user_detail.php?cId=$1 [NC,L]
```

thanks in advance to help me.

Comment: Does you page load properly when you open: `http://username.domainname.com/`?

Comment: yes, it works with id only.

Comment: But there is no id in `http://username.domainname.com/`?

Comment: sorry "userid" --> http://username.domainname.com/userid, works fine

Comment: And i need http://username.domainname.com/

Comment: I very well know you want to remove and make it `username.domainname.com` but my question is if you open `username.domainname.com` in browser will it load correct content since `userid` is missing from URL now?

Comment: no, it redirect to home page

Comment: Probably you're not getting my question. I don't to repeat my question again & again.

Comment: sorry please, the answer is NO

Comment: Well in that case you cannot remove `userid` from URL (and why do you want to remove it there is no SEO reason)

Comment: there is anyway to hide this, because it is looks like the users home page (it is also need for users)

Comment: How can you hide it? UserA has URL: `username.domainname.com/userid1` and UserB will have: `username.domainname.com/userid2` if you remove `userid` then both will have same page.

Comment: in my mysql table, username and userid are unique And username is for his/her sitename

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i wrote a set of code in php page, which is finely working. in index page, include the following code :

```
$cId=0;
 $url=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
 $a= explode(".",$url);
 $objComp = new mysql_profile();
    $arrOrg= $objComp->select_admin_profileorgs(0);
    if($a[1]!='bgrow')
    {
      if(count($arrOrg) > 0)
    {  
        for($i=0;$i<count($arrOrg);$i++){ 
         $cUrl = $arrOrg[$i]['cUrl'];
         if((strtolower($cUrl) == $a[0]) || (strtolower($cUrl) == $a[1])) {  
            include($PATH."domain.com/user_detail.php");
         }
    }   
    } 
    }
    else { // inderpage content }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this rule for redirection:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.domainname\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^\w+/?$ / [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domainname\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /user_detail.php?cName=%1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: That is as per your requirement

Comment: And  username.domainname.com/userid returns "404 not found"

Comment: Did URL become `username.domainname.com` or not?

Comment: What do you mean by home page? URL changed to `username.domainname.com` right?

Comment: no, it shows the "http://domainname.com/index.php" with the url "username.domainname.com"

Comment: That is all this 301 rule can do. Now what internal URL do you wnt to show for `http://username.domainname.com`?

Comment: `(i is any number)`: And where will that number come from since URL `username.domainname.com` doesn't have it anymore.

Comment: i know that, but i need to remove or hide the userid. is there a way to hide the userid?

Comment: Well it is removed from URL, as you said but now it cannot come back in `/user_detail.php?cId=1234`

Comment: so is there no way to remove or hide the userid?!

Comment: That is what I have been trying to convey once `userid` is removed from URL you just loose it. It cannot come back by some magic

Comment: hi, i changed my primary settings with username instead of userid, can now i get the solution?!

Comment: So it is `userid.domainname.com` now instead of `username.domainname.com`?

Comment: no no, as per my request i have userid as primary, now i changed it to username. i.e : /user_detail.php?cName=abc.. something.

Comment: in you gave code, the url is changed like http://www.username.domainname.com/, but it not get the username in get() method in user_detail.php page

Comment: it shows the "domainname.com/index.php"; with the url "username.domainname.com"

Comment: I don't have any rule for `index.php` as you can see